# generating random baseband signal in matlab

Tags: matlab

How would you use the MATLAB commands conv & randn to generate a random baseband signal of a specified bandwidth in MATLAB?

I have the equation: m=conv(randn(1,9501),ones(1,500))/100, which [supposedly] produces a bandwidth of about 20Hz, but I don't understand how to modify the signal to obtain the desired bandwidth of 10Hz.

I want to apply this signal in QAM and SSB-SC.

Comment: `randn`--> white noise. To get a random signal of specific bandwidth you need to filter the white noise. Low-pass-filtering = convolution with...? I'm leaving the answer up to you, because this feels a bit like your homework to me...

Comment: @Joseph R. LPF=convolution with a sinc, since the FT of a sinc is a rectangular pulse (ideal filter) and convolution in time corresponds to multiplication in the frequency domain. Does that mean I can generate white noise and convolve it with a sinc to get the desired bandwidth?